# If I fly around mountains, can AA still damage my planes?

Tags: world-of-warships

In light of [this post](https://forum.worldofwarships.com/topic/53235-aa-shooting-through-mountains-working-as-intended/), I'm asking for games against real-life human opponents (like Random or Ranked), not Co-op or Training.

I'm playing CVs, and want to know if I ought fly around mountains to avoid  enemy ships' AA while I approach them.

Answer (score 1):

Since the date of this posting (after the CV rework),
 flying around mountains can allow you to avoid enemy ships' AA fire.

Just make sure there is no clear line-of-sight between your planes and the ship when flying around the terrains.

The line-of-sight on a ship starts from the highest point of the ship.
And by 'highest point', it means a point in the ship where:

- It is the highest point
- It can be hit by a  projectile. (Has a hitbox)

*Additionally*, the ships will not be able to spot your plane if there is a terrain blocking the line-of-sight between your plane and the ship.
(Unless someone else is spotting your plane for the other ship)